# EF core chamada de procedure

Tags: asp, entity-framework-core

Estou tentando usar o [entity-framework-core](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) e estou com um problema, preciso fazer chamada de um `procedure`:

```
var status = _context.Set<Usuario>().FromSql("exec LoginUsuario @chave='ROBr', @senha=null,@fonteConfiavel=0").ToList();
```

Erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The required column 'ID' was not
>   present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'

Comment: Tenho uma suspeita do que seja, mas não certeza, por isso vou adicionar aqui no comentários, tente da seguinte forma `var status = _context.Set<Usuario>().FromSql("exec LoginUsuario @p0, @p1, @p2", parameters: new[] {"ROBr", null, "0" }).ToList();`

Comment: Pelo erro parece que está faltando algum parâmetro na `procedure`. Bem especifico parece que falta o `ID`

Comment: Então ainda não deu certo,porem capturei a chamada da procedure : exec sp_executesql N'exec LoginUsuario @chave,@senha,@fonteConfiavel
',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'ROBr',@p1=NULL,@p2=N'true' ,os parametros estão vindo errados deveria ser chva,nome e fonteDesconhecida

Comment: var status = _context.Set<Usuario>().FromSql("exec LoginUsuario @chave,@senha,@fonteDesconhecida", parameters: new[] { "ROBr", null, "true" }).ToList();

Comment: Duas coisas: i) Tente remover o "exec" do `FromSql` `FromSql(" LoginUsuario....`; ii) Rodando `exec LoginUsuario "ROBr", null, 0` direto no banco de dados, da certo?

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'LoginUsuario
',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 int',@p0=N'@chave=rob',@p1=NULL,@p2=0 ,esse é chamada e testei no banco e da o mesmo erro Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure LoginUsuario, Line 73
Procedure or function 'LoginUsuario' expects parameter '@chave', which was not supplied.

Comment: está faltando passar parâmetros para sua `procedure`

Comment: coloque a procedure na sua pergunta!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para chamar um [Stored Procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) no [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/) existem duas opções no método [FromSql](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) e [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx). O [FromSql](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) é utilizado para retorno (`SELECT`) e já o [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) para inserir, alterar e excluir dados de um tabela, basicamente é isso.

Pelo código da pergunta existe erro na criação do parâmetros que a `Stored Procedure` precisava para funcionar, então, com um ***exemplo minimo*** vou explicar como deveria fazer o código:

- `FromSql` (com retorno de informações)

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_Login] 
    @UserName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    SELECT * FROM [Login] WHERE [Login].[UserName] = @UserName;
END
```

Para utilizar o código é muito simples, crie um `SqlParameter` com todos os parâmetros que precisa utilizar e passe o valor correspondente e após é só chamar a sua `Procedure` pelo método [FromSql](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) do mesmo jeito que foi criado no seu banco:

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{              
    var param = new SqlParameter("@UserName", "Us1");
    var result = db.Login
                   .FromSql("Proc_Login @UserName", param)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

---

- `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Update_Passord_Login 
    @Password varchar(50),
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN           
    UPDATE [Login] SET [Login].[Password] = @Password WHERE [Login].[Id] = @Id;
END
```

Para utilizar essa `procedure` de atualização utilize no seu `DbContext` o [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx) da seguinte forma:

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{    
    var parameters = new[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@Password", "abcd"),
        new SqlParameter("@Id", 1)
    };
    int count = db.Database
        .ExecuteSqlCommand("Proc_Update_Passord_Login @Password, @Id", parameters);

}
```

onde a variavel `count` retorna o número de linhas que foram afetadas.

---

***Voltando*** *a sua pergunta com base nessa explicação é simples a solução*:

```
var parameters = new[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@chave", "abcd"),
    new SqlParameter("@senha", null),
    new SqlParameter("@fonteConfiavel", 0)
};
var status = _context.Set<Usuario>()
                    .FromSql("LoginUsuario @chave,@senha,@fonteConfiavel", parameters)
                    .ToList();
```

***Nota:*** *Não sei como está a sua* [Stored Procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)*, por isso os parâmetros foram utilizado igual na perguntando, possa ser que precise de algum ajuste por algum erro inesperado, mas, o exemplo dando anteriormente é funcional.*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Visão geral rápida do Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/)
- [Working with Stored Procedure in Entity Framework Core](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx)
- [How to execute Stored Procedure in Entity Framework Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core/)

Answer (score 0):

Bom achei uma solução para chamada de procedure no entity framework core,seguem abaixo a solução que eu encontrei:

```
var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
//Abrir conexão com o banco.
_context.Database.GetDbConnection().Open();
//Chama a sua procedure.
cmd.CommandText = "LoginUsuario";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//Passar os parametros necessarios para chamar a procedure.
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@chave", email));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@senha", senha));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fonteConfiavel", false));
//Executar a chamada.
using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{

   List<LoginUsuario> listobjet = new List<LoginUsuario>();  
   foreach (var item in rd)
   {

       LoginUsuario loginUsuario = new LoginUsuario();
       // Aqui voce coloca os pametro que retorna da procedure.
       loginUsuario.Cookie = rd[0].ToString();
       loginUsuario.LoginStatus = Convert.ToInt32(rd[1].ToString());
       loginUsuario.UsuarioID = Convert.ToInt32(rd[2].ToString());
       listobjet.Add(loginUsuario);

   }
   //Fechar conexão
   _context.Database.GetDbConnection().Close();   
   //retornar os valores
    return listobjet.FirstOrDefault();

}
```